# Issue with The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java

When I try to convert this

```
if ( prop.getDateSaisie() == null ) prop.setDateSaisie(new Date()) ;
else                                prop.setDateSaisieModif(new Date()) ;
```

To the Java ternary operator like this

```
prop.getDateSaisie() == null ? prop.setDateSaisie(new Date()) : prop.setDateSaisieModif(new Date()) ;
```

I got `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`

So i have to do it whith `if` `else` or i miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this using a **ternary operator**, since you are calling a different method for each condition branch. *(Besides, using a ternary operator means that you must have an assignment statement at the beginnning of the expression, which you don't in this case)* Just use a regular `if/else` statement:

```
if(prop.getDateSaisie() == null) 
    prop.setDateSaisie(new Date());
else
    prop.setDateSaisieModif(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the compiler error: *left hand side must be a variable*.
The point of the ternary or "conditional" operator is to introduce conditionals into an *expression*.

Meaning you have to write the ternary operator in this fashion:

```
variable = condition ? true : false;
```

Answer (score -1):

It **can't be done** using ternary operator